# No permitir mas de un espacio Edit Text

Tags: java, android-studio

estoy intentando averiguar como puedo hacer que el usuario no pueda introducir mas de un espacio en una cadena.

```
if (!et_actualiza.getText().toString().contains("  ")){
    AutoCompletarCerca.agafarNoms(et_actualiza.getText().toString(),
            groups,UnProducte,Productes,ArrayNom,ArrayFormulat,ArrayNumRegistre,ArrayTitular);
}else if(et_actualiza.getText().toString().contains()){

}else{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error, no s'admiten caracteres especiales/demasiados espacios.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Tengo de momento esto lo tengo puesto con 2 espacios pero si quisiera que sea de 2 espacios o más seria infinitos los `ifs`.

Comment: ¿Más de un espacio **consecutivo**?

Comment: Si, que sea por ejemplo "HOLA__AMIGO" hay 2 espacios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sin usar librerías, el manejo de expresiones regulares en Java no es trivial, pero podrías hacer algo como:

```
if (Pattern.compile(" {2,}").matcher(et_actualiza.getText().toString()).find()) {
    //hay 2 o más espacios seguidos
```

}

Otra opción sería crearte un método auxiliar que busque espacios consecutivos.

```
private boolean tieneEspaciosConsecutivos(String s){
    boolean espacioPrevio = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) == ' ') { 
            if (espacioPrevio) {
                return true;
            else {
                espacioPrevio = false;
            }
        }
        espacioPrevio = false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

No es tan bonito, pero seguramente sea más eficiente que usar una RegExp

Comment: La primera opción me funciona perfectamente, imagino que el espacio que hay dentro es el valor que se usa para encontrar si hay 2 o más? " {2,}"

Comment: Correcto, al poner un caracter seguido de `{n,m}`, indicas que quieres buscar ese caracter (o grupo de ellos) repetido entre `n` y `m` veces, siendo ambos parámetros opcionales

Comment: Resulta mas practico así entonces. Gracias muy amable!